# WCF prevent NetNamedPipeBinding Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I have created a simple client-service setup for downloading applications from a server. The client creates a NetNamedPipeBinding and uses this to open a channel with the service to initiate the download process.

```
private void OpenServiceChannel()
    {            
        InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);

        NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

        DuplexChannelFactory<ICloudProductService> duplexChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ICloudProductService>(instanceContext, binding, new EndpointAddress(ADDRESS));

        _proxy = duplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

The service then uses a Callback on the same channel to report progress to the client. This callback is defined as a part of the ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IStatusProgressCallback))]
public interface ICloudProductService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceErrorCode))]
    Task<IEnumerable<LauncherAppDetails>> GetAvailableApps(string tokenJson);

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceErrorCode))]
    Task Install(string tokenJson, LauncherAppDetails app);
}
```

With the event in said callback triggered by the Service when it needs to increment the download progress

```
public interface IStatusProgressCallback
{

    [OperationContract]
    void OnProgressUpdated(InstallProgress progress);

}
```

This all works beautifully on any half decent internet connection as the downloads are pretty fast. My issue is that on slow connections, the download is taking longer than the 1 minute default timeout for the binding. I could increase the timeout of this binding but I am concerned that this is not an ideal solution as it is bad practice due to possible security/performance issues.

Is there a way of configuring the binding on the client side so that the timeout period is refreshed on each successful callback (a keep-alive) such that as long as the server is passing incremental download progress, the connection will not time out.

Comment: Have you considered using an asynchronous service? Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-service-operation.

Comment: I hadn't but i will take a look into this. thanks

Comment: I don't think that using NetNamedPipeBinding for over-internet-download is good idea since it's designed for on-machine communication. You should consider NetTcpBinding or NetHttpBinding.

Comment: Well the download and the installation all happens within the Service. The client simply kicks off the process and reports progress. Ill certainly look into these options though thanks